# ReactiveUI - Binding ReactiveList<object> to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, reactiveui

I'm having a problem using ReactiveUI to bind a `ReactiveList<object>` on my ViewModel to the SelectedItems property (`ObservableCollection<object>`) of a control in my WPF view. I tried:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SelectedItems, x => x.CBSelect.SelectedItems);
```

but I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in ReactiveUI.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Can't two-way convert between ReactiveUI.ReactiveList[System.Object] and System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[System.Object]. To fix this, register a IBindingTypeConverter

I saw that Paul Betts had recommended a different approach in another post using:

```
 this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.countries.SelectedItems)
    .Select(list => list.Cast<Country>())
    .BindTo(this, x => x.ViewModel.SelectedCountries);
```

I tried this but I get a similar error to the first:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in ReactiveUI.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Can't convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[System.Object] to ReactiveUI.ReactiveList[System.Object]. To fix this, register a IBindingTypeConverter

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: I think your issue isn't really related to ReactiveUI - you'd have this problem with any or no framework.  `SelectedItems` properties are usually read-only, so you can't bind to them.  The usual solution is to create an attached property or behavior that syncs between the two (listening for changes on each and insert/removing on the other).

Comment: You're right about the read-only nature of SelectedItems. I was distracted by the error message. I'll implement something to keep them in sync as you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to save some time, do some googling - I'm sure many others have implemented this!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a very late answer, but what you could do using ReactiveUI is something like this. Add [*reactiveui-events-* package](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/events/) for your platform and then in view code add this:

```
this.WhenActivated(d => {
            d(this.countries.Events()
                .SelectionChanged
                .Subscribe(ea => {
                    using (ViewModel.SelectedCountries.SuppressChangeNotifications())
                    {
                        ViewModel.SelectedCountries.RemoveAll(ea.RemovedItems.Cast<Country>());
                        ViewModel.SelectedCountries.AddRange(ea.AddedItems.Cast<Country>());
                    }
                }));
        });
```

This way you will get a reactive list that will change on user interaction and you can react to those changes in view model.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to bind `SelectedItems` directly to the property and avoid dealing with `SelectionChanged` event args

```
this.DataGrid1.Events().SelectionChanged
    .Select(x => this.DataGrid1.SelectedItems.Cast<CountryModel>())
    .BindTo(this, x => x.ViewModel.SelectedCountries);
```

Please note that `SelectedCountries` is an `IEnumerable` as other events are triggered when it is updated.